# Ruby on Rails session with different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, my application has 3 Models: Series, Season, Chapter.

As you could think, Series has multiple seasons and Season has multiple chapters. They are all "products" that can be bought by the client.

When a user clicks on the button **buy it**, I do the following code:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def addproduct
    (session[:products] ||= []) << params[:item]
    redirect_back(fallback_location: "/", flash: {from_add_product: true})
  end
end
```

This `:item` is the object containing all the information of the object (Series, Season or Chapter).

The main problem is that this just saves the primary key of the Model, not the object. So when I have to loop over it on `cart.html.erb` I have serious problems because I don't know what is a Series, a Season or a Chapter.

```
<% session[:products].each do |element| %>
```

Is there any way of doing this better?

Comment: what does `params[:item].inspect` show?

Comment: how I can see that?

Comment: You can use a debugger like the pry gem or do it the caveman way and raise an exception, `raise params[:item].inspect` :)

Comment: You need to pass another parameter to specify whether the item is a serie, seaon, or chapter.  Can you show your view code?

Comment: You don't want to pass the whole object from your view... ideally you just want the id and some indication of which model it is.

Comment: exactly what information do you want to include in the session? Inside the controller action, you can lookup the record using the id param including whatever extra data you need to show, then store that in the session.

Comment: Agree with @SteveTurczyn, if you do sth like `(session[:products] ||= []) << "ModelIdentifier_#{params[:item]}` later you will be able to figure out the model

Comment: How I can store what kind of model is, so I can take all series chapters ans seasons separately?

Comment: @Kris after using inspect this :item only contains the primary key of the object passed. How I can pass the whole object?